# Pass Artifact to Azure devops Rest api POST method

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to pass artifact from build pipeline to release pipeline using REST API call. But I couldn't find an option to pass the artifact source or artifact name . The json body i am using is given below

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "test release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
    "alias": "Customer.CI",
    "instanceReference": {
     "id": "2",
     "name": null
     }
  }
 ],
 "isDraft": false,
 "reason": "none",
 "manualEnvironments": null
 }
```

ALso the rest api call is as below

```
    $Uri=https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/Orgname/ProjName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $bodyString -Headers $header
```

How to pass different artifact at run time during the POST API call of the release pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rest api you call, you should want to set the artifact list when creating the release, then the artifacts should be able to be passed in the `"artifacts"` of the request body, as the json body you showed in the question.

The `"alias"` variable should be your **build definition name**, The `"id"` and `"name"` variables in the `"instanceReference"` specify the ID and name of the artifact source. You can also compare it when creating the release manually in web access, as shown below (The **Version** should be the “ID” of the build):

[image]
[image]

If I misunderstand this issue , please point it out.